# Lock Screen Shell Script Troubles

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, lockscreen

So I've been messing around with the lockscreen in windows 10. What I've done is created a batch script that will swap out the lockscreen every time I log into my computer such that every time I come to my PC, a new image from a group of pre-selected images will be displayed.

---

Here is the code:

```
cd C:\Lockscreen Application
set /a count=0
for /F %%N in ('dir/s/b/a-d "%~dp0LockScreenPictures\lockscreen*.png"^|findstr /ric:"\\lockscreen[0-9][0-9]*\.png$"^|find /c /v ""') do set count=%%N
echo count=%count%
set r=%time:~-2%
echo r
set first=%r:~0,1% 
if %first%==0 set r=%r:~1,1%
set /a r=(%r%%%(%count%)) + 1
echo rand=%r%
SET ls=lockscreen%r%
echo %ls%
copy LockScreenPictures\%ls%.png LockScreenDestination\lockscreen.png
start ms-settings:lockscreen
timeout 1
taskkill /f /IM SystemSettings.exe
```

---

The script is running in a folder called `Lockscreen Application` with two additional folders inside of it; `LockScreenDestination` and `LockScreenPictures`

`LockScreenPictures` contains the group of pictures that the script randomly selects one from. All have the name `lockscreen(1-30).png`
`LockScreenDestination` always has one picture in it called `lockscreen.png` which is intended to be the current lockscreen.

In the windows Settings, I have set the lock screen option to picture and set the picture to `lockscreen.png` in the `LockScreenDestination` folder, with the intent that every time the program would run, the lockscreen would change its image to the new one with the same path in `LockScreenDestination`.

However, the problem I am running into is that even though the picture displayed in lockscreen settings page matches the picture in `LockScreenDestination`, the actual lockscreen picture wont change from the original `image.png` that I gave it when I was configuring the lockscreen settings originally.

I'm not sure how to fix this so any suggestions/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Your post has some formatting issues that makes it hard to understand/read. Please see [how do I format my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) topic in the help center.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not a programming issue.  It is more of a Windows System issue which is out of scope for StackOverFlow.